# Need help for $lookup $nin mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections in Mongodb `product` and `review`.

`product` collection contains:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d15830d879652dad55e23"), 
    "productId" : "0001"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d15b79bc9dd5940f5ff28"), 
    "productId" : "0002"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d15bd9bc9dd5940f5ff29"), 
    "productId" : "0003"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d15c29bc9dd5940f5ff2a"), 
    "productId" : "0004"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d186b9bc9dd5940f5ff2f"), 
    "productId" : "0005"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d18719bc9dd5940f5ff30"), 
    "productId" : "0006"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d18789bc9dd5940f5ff31"), 
    "productId" : "0007"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d187d9bc9dd5940f5ff32"), 
    "productId" : "0008"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d18829bc9dd5940f5ff33"), 
    "productId" : "0009"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d18889bc9dd5940f5ff34"), 
    "productId" : "0010"
}
```

and the `review` collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d15ce0d879652dad55e24"), 
    "userId" : "1", 
    "exclusion" : [
        "0002", 
        "0003"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d185d9bc9dd5940f5ff2e"), 
    "userId" : "2", 
    "exclusion" : [
        "0001", 
        "0002", 
        "0003"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d18df9bc9dd5940f5ff35"), 
    "userId" : "3", 
    "exclusion" : [
        "0001", 
        "0002", 
        "0003", 
        "0004", 
        "0005", 
        "0006", 
        "0007"
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d19379bc9dd5940f5ff36"), 
    "userId" : "4", 
    "exclusion" : [
        "0002", 
        "0003", 
        "0004", 
        "0007", 
        "0008", 
        "0009"
    ]
}
```

And I would like to show product who are not in the exclusion array of a specific user.

Example: if I am the user `4`, I want to see product `0001`, `0005`, `0006` and `0010` only. I have tried many things like `$lookup` but it was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** based on comments.

If `product` collection is shareded, then try this:

```js
db.product.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            products: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "review",
            let: { products: "$products" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: { userId: "4" }
                },
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        products: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$$products",
                                as: "product",
                                cond: {
                                    $not: {
                                        $in: ["$$product.productId", "$exclusion"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "reviews"
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $first: "$reviews" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("604d19379bc9dd5940f5ff36"),
    "userId" : "4",
    "exclusion" : [
        "0002",
        "0003",
        "0004",
        "0007",
        "0008",
        "0009"
    ],
    "products" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("604d15830d879652dad55e23"),
            "productId" : "0001"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("604d186b9bc9dd5940f5ff2f"),
            "productId" : "0005"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("604d18719bc9dd5940f5ff30"),
            "productId" : "0006"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("604d18889bc9dd5940f5ff34"),
            "productId" : "0010"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!, your querry is working but i have forgot to say the products collection will be sharded, only the review collection will not be sharded, so i cannot use this querry. How can i do for make this querry working  ?

Comment: Sorry I have no experience on sharded collections. Mention it in the question and someone else might help.

Comment: When a collection is sharded you need to start with the sharded collection and make the "from" into the lookup with non-sharded collection.

Comment: Ok this detail helped. Check the updated answer.

Comment: What is your MongoDB version? I have used some 4.4(latest) operators.

Comment: Thank you so much for yoru help, is  working like a charm !!! I also use the 4.4 version of mongoDB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229896/discussion-between-harima34-and-dheemanth-bhat).